# sbt not resolving dependency; path correct except ${package.type} extension

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.13

sbt (0.13.8) is failing to resolve the dependency in the following extremely simple `build.sbt`:

```
organization := "edu.umass.cs.iesl"

name := "nn-depparse"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers += "IESL snapshot repository" at "https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies += "cc.factorie" %% "factorie" % "1.2-SNAPSHOT"

parallelExecution := true
```

For some reason it resolves the following path:

https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cc/factorie/factorie_2.11/1.2-SNAPSHOT/factorie_2.11-1.2-20151007.170205-28.${package.type}

Rather than the correct path to the jar:

https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cc/factorie/factorie_2.11/1.2-SNAPSHOT/factorie_2.11-1.2-20151007.170205-28.jar

It seems as though `${package.type}` is being interpreted as a literal file extension rather than whatever the contents of the variable `package.type`, but I have no idea why; I am using the simplest possible build configuration! As far as I know, I don't have any weird sbt configurations lying around (or any at all -- I checked `~/.sbt`, and I have tried running on multiple machines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A following line found in [factorie_2.11-1.2-20151007.170205-28.pom](https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cc/factorie/factorie_2.11/1.2-SNAPSHOT/factorie_2.11-1.2-20151007.170205-28.pom):

```
<packaging>${package.type}</packaging>
```

I suppose sbt uses this setting to get the artifact.

In the [previous .pom file](https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cc/factorie/factorie_2.11/1.2-SNAPSHOT/factorie_2.11-1.2-20141218.164543-27.pom),  it has:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

So, maybe it's a broken build.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it would be a build issue in the main project since a) that build was fine and b) I was only having downstream problems in sbt but not maven (I'm surprised I didn't find others having issues with this lack of variable substitution?)

Answer (score 4):

As @kawty says it does look like the `pom` in question is malformed, but in terms of fixing your sbt script, you can change you dependency line to:

```
libraryDependencies += "cc.factorie" %% "factorie" % "1.2-SNAPSHOT" artifacts( Artifact("factorie", "", "jar"))
```

to manually specify the extension of the artifact that you want.

Comment: Thanks, also a useful answer (particularly for those who may have the same issue but are not owners of the upstream project)!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but the pom does not exist.  I've tried this method and it didn't work. Any suggestions?